# Find geometrical meaning of $[a,b]^3$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, general-topology, analytic-geometry

Find geometrical meaning of

$a)$$[a,b] \times [c,d] $ ($cartesian$ product)

$b$)$[a,b]^3$

$a)$ is easy it is rectangle

but what say about $b$? Is it parallelepiped?

Comment: "but what about $b$?" Well, $b$ is the second entry after $a$ in $[a,b]$ - and $[a,b]^3$ is a cuboid, right? Start first with $[a,b]^2$.

Comment: Note that $[a,b]^3$ means $[a,b] \times [a,b] \times [a,b]$. Therefore...

Comment: @unit 1991 How do you define interval multiplication?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer is it the case $(X \times Y) \times Z = X \times (Y \times Z)$

Comment: Hint:  What do we call raising something to the third power?

Comment: Technically, no, but they're isomorphic in a sense that they can be treated identically most of the time. (For instance, $\Bbb R^3$ is 3-dimensional space, but what would $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R^2$, $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R$, or $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ be like?)